# MDX for inner query Max Date filter

Tags: ssas, mdx, performancepoint

I need to create MDX query for a PerformancePoint report based on following SQL, any ideas?  pointers?

```
SELECT count(*), sum(balance) FROM SerialBalance b  
WHERE  balance > 0 
AND EffectiveDate = (   Select  Max(EffectiveDate) 
            From    SerialBalance sb 
            Where   SB.Subhead  = b.Subhead
            and SB.SerialNumber = b.SerialNumber 
            and SB.Branch   = b.Branch 
            and SB.Zone     = b.Zone
            and SB.Country  = b.Country
            and SB.EffectiveDate <= '2013-05-31'
            )
```

Comment: What measures and dimensions are in your cube? The statement you have provided above is a SQL statement which is against tabular data. If you nee it in an MDX Format you would have to query against a multidimensional format such as a SSAS Cube.